# How to perform a 2-way Friedman test in R

Tags: r

My study results look as follows:

```
id gender result 
1     F     2.3
1     F     2.5
1     F     2.6
2     M     3.1
2     M     3.2
2     M     3.0
```

That is, I have the gender category, and repeated measures. However, the repeated measures are separated, as the participants is either male or female.

I was thinking of doing two way Friedman test, since my results are not normally distributed.

My problem: I could not find it in r. I did find how to perform a one-way Friedman, but it seems that it is not my case, and I need a two-way.

If necessary, I can rearrange my data so each participant will be in a separate row, if that will help in a way.

I need something like this, only using r:
http://www.nyx.net/~tmacfarl/STAT_TUT/friedman.ssi

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: `install.package('sos')`, `library(sos)`, `findFn('Friedman test')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to compare male and females why dont you use Mann-Whitney U test instead?

Answer (score 1):

According to this article: http://www.gardenersown.co.uk/education/lectures/r/nonparam.htm#friedman

You should use the built-in `friedman.test()` function.

Comment: Thanks, I also saw this tutorial before. However, it seems it is not my case, since the participants are not performing the same trials. This is why I'm looking for a 2-way and not one-way.